# Ace vs King and Queen (texas holdem)

Tags: texas-hold-em

Who wins? I had King and Queen while my friend had Ace and 2. We got in an argue. Please explain and thanks. (we played texas holdem)

Comment: I think this is not a duplicate

Comment: @David This is a duplicate. Short clarification though: OP's friend had Ace high, OP had King high. Ace high wins unless the community cards combined make a straight, flush or a full house. The kicker (other hand) is irrelevant when comparing high cards that play. OP's friend wins.

Comment: Thank you good sir, that is what i thought but there is always a second opinion.